# how to implement a retweet tracker on Android

Tags: android, twitter, tracker

I would like to know if there is a way to track these retweets... I know that there are several applications for full twitter already available, but i would like to follow just a few things and integrate them in my application...
The only thing I'm sure of, is that when someone retweet one of my tweets, there is a @my_account mentionned somewhere. But I have know idea of how to deal with it...
If you had any lead for me, that would be great.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) jar to your project and use that to query for retweets.

Comment: yep, I found that jar before seeing your answer. I'll have a look, it seems perfect.
thx!